# Button does not print a string on the dev console

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to test if my button is working by logging a text on the dev console. But when I click on the button I don't see it printing on the console.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css',
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() text!: string;
  @Input() color!: string;
  @Output() btnClick = new EventEmitter();

  onClick() {
    this.btnClick.emit();
  }
}
 <button
   [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': color }"
   class="btn"
   (click)="(onClick)"
 >
   {{ text }}
</button>
<header>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <app-button
   color="green"
   text="Add"
   (btnClick)="toggleAddTask()"
  ></app-button>
</header>
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { ButtonComponent } from '../button/button.component';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-header',
   standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.css',
  imports: [ButtonComponent],
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  title: string = 'Task Tracker';

  toggleAddTask() {
    console.log('Toggleee Toggleee');
  }
}
```

I tried to test if my button worked by printing something on the dev console.

Comment: <button
  [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': color }"
  class="btn"
  (click)="onClick()" <!-- Corrected this line -->
>
  {{ text }}
</button>

Answer (score 2):

I see one possible reason, `(click)="(onClick)"` should probably be `(click)="onClick()"`, you must define `onClick` function

Comment: Thank you so much, this was it!  Sorry for the negligence